# How can I replace the values in one pyspark dataframe column with the values from another column in a sub-section of the dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, pivot

I have to perform a group-by and pivot operation on a dataframe's "activity" column, and populate the new columns resulting from the pivot with the sum of the "quantity" column. One of the activity columns, however has to be populated with the sum of the "cost" column.

Data frame before group-by and pivot:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| id | quantity  | cost      | activity  | category  | 
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |         2 |         2 |    skiing |   outdoor |
|  2 |         0 |         2 |  swimming |  outdoor  |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

pivot code:

pivotDF = df.groupBy("category").pivot("activity").sum("quantity")

result:

```
    +----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
    | id | category  | skiing    | swimming  | 
    +----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
    |  1 |   outdoor |    2      |   5       |
    |  2 |   outdoor |    4      |   7       |
    +----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

The problem is that for one of these activities, I need the activity column to be populated with sum("cost") instead of sum("quantity"). I can't seem to find a way to specify this during the pivot operation itself, so I thought maybe I can just exchange the values in the quantity column for the ones in the cost column wherever the activity column value corresponds to the relevant activity. However, I can't find an example of how to do this in a pyspark data frame.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide more than 1 aggregation after the `pivot`.

Let's say the input dataframe looks like the following

```
# +---+---+----+--------+-------+
# | id|qty|cost|     act|    cat|
# +---+---+----+--------+-------+
# |  1|  2|   2|  skiing|outdoor|
# |  2|  0|   2|swimming|outdoor|
# |  3|  1|   2|  skiing|outdoor|
# |  4|  2|   4|swimming|outdoor|
# +---+---+----+--------+-------+
```

Do a `pivot` and use `agg()` to provide more than 1 aggregation.

```
data_sdf. \
    groupBy('id', 'cat'). \
    pivot('act'). \
    agg(func.sum('cost').alias('cost'), 
        func.sum('qty').alias('qty')
        ). \
    show()

# +---+-------+-----------+----------+-------------+------------+
# | id|    cat|skiing_cost|skiing_qty|swimming_cost|swimming_qty|
# +---+-------+-----------+----------+-------------+------------+
# |  2|outdoor|       null|      null|            2|           0|
# |  1|outdoor|          2|         2|         null|        null|
# |  3|outdoor|          2|         1|         null|        null|
# |  4|outdoor|       null|      null|            4|           2|
# +---+-------+-----------+----------+-------------+------------+
```

Notice the field names. Pyspark automatically assigned the suffix based on the `alias` provided in the aggregations. Use a `drop` or `select` to retain the columns required and rename them per your choice.

---

Removing `id` from the `groupBy` makes the result much better.

```
data_sdf. \
    groupBy('cat'). \
    pivot('act'). \
    agg(func.sum('cost').alias('cost'), 
        func.sum('qty').alias('qty')
        ). \
    show()

# +-------+-----------+----------+-------------+------------+
# |    cat|skiing_cost|skiing_qty|swimming_cost|swimming_qty|
# +-------+-----------+----------+-------------+------------+
# |outdoor|          4|         3|            6|           2|
# +-------+-----------+----------+-------------+------------+
```